# Unable to execute a bash script containing docker commands from a php file

Tags: php, shell, docker

I am running the following php script. It creates a script file which runs a couple of docker commands. But this script file doesn't run the docker commands for some reason. It does run normal script file commands like ls, pwd, echoetc.

```
$code = $_POST['source']; 
$myfile = fopen("abc.py", "w");
fwrite($myfile, $code);
$myfile_new = fopen("execu_ta.sh", "w");
$txt = "#!/bin/bash\n\n";
fwrite($myfile_new, $txt);
$txt1 = "docker build -t python-new-world .";  
$txt2 = "docker run python-new-world\n";
fwrite($myfile_new, $txt1);
fwrite($myfile_new, $txt2);
$result=shell_exec('path of the "execu_ta.sh" file');
echo $result;

?>
```

What might be wrong here?

Comment: you need to set executable bit or use `shell_exec('/bin/bash your_script')`

Comment: @Ujin, maybe you could add your comment as an answer so you could get credit for it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set executable bit `chmod("your script filename", 0755);` or use `shell_exec('/bin/bash your_script')`

Comment: Then why does it run shell commands? Could it be the script exists and has the necessary permissions?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Ujin's answer, I'd flush and close the file too, or you may end up executing an empty script. Make sure docker is on your PATH.